# Игра-тренажер для быстрой печати на юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хочу сделать на юнити такую механику для игры, когда персонаж сталкивается с врагом появляются 4 кнопки с рандомными буквами. Игрок вводит символы и если он совпадает с символами на кнопках, то продолжает игру. Если же какой-то из символов не совпал, то персонаж погибает.
Пробовала создавать массив и посимвольно сравнивать, но когда в массиве присутствуют одинаковые буквы, то успевает засчитать их обе (в общем не особо рабочий вариант)
Буду благодарна любой помощи

Comment: код прикрепите.